# Add a row below a specific row

Tags: html, jquery, html-table, tr

I want to add a row below another but it is added at the end.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <table style="width: 200px" border="1">
      <tr>
        <th style="width: 100px">A</th>
        <th style="width: 100px">B</th>
      </tr>
      <tr id="info">
        <td>Data1</td>
        <td>Data2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2">C</th>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br />
    <button type="button" onclick="AddRow()">Add Row</button>
  </body>
</html>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function AddRow() {
    $('#info').parent().append('<tr><td>Data3</td><td>Data4</td></tr>');
  }
</script>
```

I would like it to be added as follows. Is there a way to achieve this?

[image: demo]

Comment: [jQuery DOM insertion methods, inside](https://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-inside/) and [jQuery DOM insertion methods, outside](https://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-outside/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent of `tr#info` is the `table` itself. Therefore when you `append()` to that   `table` the content is placed at the end.

To do what you require select `#info` and use `after()` to insert the content directly after the target:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('.add-row').on('click', () => {
    $('#info').after('<tr><td>Data3</td><td>Data4</td></tr>');
  });
});
```

```css
table { width: 200px; }
th { width: 100px; }
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>A</th>
    <th>B</th>
  </tr>
  <tr id="info">
    <td>Data1</td>
    <td>Data2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">C</th>
  </tr>
</table><br />

<button type="button" class="add-row">Add Row</button>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
```

Also note in the example above that I moved the inline CSS to an external stylesheet and the inline JS event handler to an unobtrusive one attached via jQuery. Your HTML should ideally contain no code other than HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You should use jQuery after() function - https://api.jquery.com/after/

Example:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <table style="width: 200px" border="1">
      <tr>
        <th style="width: 100px">A</th>
        <th style="width: 100px">B</th>
      </tr>
      <tr id="info">
        <td>Data1</td>
        <td>Data2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2">C</th>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br />
    <button type="button" onclick="AddRow()">Add Row</button>
  </body>
</html>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function AddRow() {
    $('#info').after('<tr><td>Data3</td><td>Data4</td></tr>');
  }
</script>
```